# Paging through a large set in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I am not understanding the `Skip` method in LINQ - I have data that comes back from a web service. The data is fairly large and has grown over time so now I need to page through the records.

The piece code I am using is this:

```
var res = proxy.FP_MEDIA_COUNT
    .Where(x => 
        x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.PriceGroup != null &&      
        ((x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.Year > RetYear) || 
        (x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.Year == RetYear && 
        ((x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.Season == RetSeason) || 
        (x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.Season == NextSeason))))
    )
    .Select(x => new { 
        PromoID = x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.PromotionID, 
        Year = x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.Year, 
        Season = x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.Season, 
        BU = x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.PriceGroup.PriceGroupName, 
        Metric = x.Lot.Metric, 
        Lot = x.Lot, 
        Media = x.Media, 
        MediaType = x.Media.MediaType, 
        MediaSubType = x.MediaSubType 
     })
     .Take(10)
     .ToArray();
```

I see how to use the `Take` method and I sort of understand the `Skip` method but any time I place it before the `Take` method I get the error message:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition.

This isn't really helpful.

Can anybody instruct me on where the `Skip` method should be placed or a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you discover [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) yet?

Comment: The `Skip` goes before the `Take` - you are basically saying `skip y records and take the next x records`.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that neither Lot, ProductGroup, Promotion, Calendar and PriceGroup are null when doing x.Lot.ProductGroup.Promotion.Calendar.PriceGroup.PriceGroupName ?

Comment: Are you sure it has something to do with `skip` operator? What about null values in your model, what if you try `take(100)`?

Comment: mipe34 & David - due to the size of the data being returned I can do about 5000 records at a time. there are something like 70,000. I am fairly sure that there are not nulls because if i take a few records out (which happens through a business process I don't understand) I can get the data just fine. Oded - yeah if i put in the SKIP operator where you say it gives me the very cryptic error message above.  I have read you need an order operator in somewhere but not sure where that might go (not real strong with LINQ)

Comment: Please post the full error including inner exceptions (I'm sure there is one) and stack traces. Please post the SQL that was executed.

Comment: Also look at `InnerException`.  There's definitely more error information than this.  We need this in order to be able to help you.

Comment: `.OrderBy(x=>x.PromoID).ThenBy(x=>x.Year).ThenBy(x=>x.Season)` after the Select, and before the .Skip